# Migrated to Magento 2 - reduced visitors in Google Analytics (but stable sales) from Organic search

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

I migrated about a month ago to Magento 2. Since then, I've experienced a sharp decline in page views and visitors. Although, sales are stable. Part of the decline was expected due to various issues related to transition (but expected it to be stabilized later on).

To recover, I started a project with targets on new visitor per traffic type. This made me realize that I, in principle,  got no **new** visitors from Organic search. Webmaster tools still shows many visitors coming from Google (but maybe, just maybe, and unlikely, they have visited the page before through direct visit).

Anyone that had similar experience? What was the cause? How did you resolve it?

**My first guess was** that this issue is related to this bug, [Analytics not tracking when Cookie restriction notice is enabled](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5596). However, I used Google Tag Assistant, and recorded an interaction with the web page and with cookies disabled, it didn't track and then, with cookies enabled, it started to track (expected behavior). I also used the Google Analytics Debugger plugin to chrome and verified that the beacon was sent once I allowed cookies.

**My second guess is** that customers don't accept the cookies and manage to shop anyway. If so, any ideas on how I could measure this? I use Apache with full access to the logs and server.

**Some analytics data**

***Overall:***

- sessions: -58.7 %
- new sessions: -22.76 %
- new users: -68.1 %
- income: -2.54 %

**Referral:**

- sessions: -62.92 %
- new sessions: -90.62 %
- new users: -96.52 %
- income: -1.58 %

**Organic search**

- sessions: -84.70 %
- new sessions: -90.15 %
- new users: -98.49 %
- income: -42.28 %

**Social**

- sessions: -95.69 %
- new sessions: -87.17 %
- new users: -99.45 %
- income: -100 %

**Direct**

- sessions: -10.35 %
- new sessions: -1.43 %
- new users: -11.63 %
- income: *233.15 %*

Some changes I did when upgrading to M2 that may impact number of visitors:

- HTTPS / TSL
- Cookie restriction notice
- Fail2Ban
- mod_pagespeed

After migrating, I spent some time reviewing the sites and my setup with Google Webmaster Tools, Google Analytics and Tag Assistant. I also later configured Analytics to exclude my own developer IP.

Using Tag Assistant, I was able to find out that [GA PageView was triggered twice](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12221). I made some changes in the .js, which removed that issue.